# ORA-01735: invalid ALTER TABLE option (While trying to change DEFAULT on a COLUMN)

Tags: sql, oracle

I was trying to change the default value of a column from Y to N. I exactly use the SQL

```
ALTER TABLE myschema.emp ALTER COLUMN is_active DEFAULT 'Y';
```

as mentioned at 
https://docs.oracle.com/javadb/10.8.3.0/ref/rrefsqlj81859.html but was getting following error

```
Error report -
ORA-01735: invalid ALTER TABLE option
01735. 00000 -  "invalid ALTER TABLE option"
*Cause:    
*Action:
```

Comment: Try to add the datatype? Or try to add SET.

ALTER TABLE myschema.emp ALTER COLUMN is_active SET DEFAULT 'Y';

Comment: That's the JavaDB syntax. JavaDB is [Oracle's implementation of Apache Derby](https://docs.oracle.com/javadb/support/overview.html). That syntax is different from the syntax of [the actual Oracle RDBMS](https://docs.oracle.com/database/121/SQLRF/statements_3001.htm#SQLRF01001). I suggest you bookmark the Oracle documentation for future reference. [Find it here](https://docs.oracle.com/database/121/SQLRF/toc.htm)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try to follow this syntax. I believe you need to put the data type there.

```
    alter table foo modify( col2 varchar2(10) default 'foo' );
```

Comment: I tried this and  it worked. ALTER TABLE myschema.emp MODIFY is_active DEFAULT 'Y'.

Comment: SET is not required in your query other wise its fine. This is what that worked for me. alter table foo modify( col2 varchar2(10)  default 'foo' );